# How to order objects of different classes based on object value

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparable

I have multiple objects set up, all implementing the same class. All of these objects have a common method, "getRatio". I want to order these objects in ascending numerical order with respect to the values of the "getRatio" method, and also have the objects call their toString methods in order. I've attempted to apply this idea, but I was only to order just the numbers themselves.

```
    List shapeList = new ArrayList();
    shapeList.add(rectangle);
    shapeList.add(triangle_right);
    shapeList.add(isosceles);
    shapeList.add(triangle);
    shapeList.add(triangle2);
    shapeList.add(triangle3);
    Collections.sort(shapeList);
    for (Shape shape : shapeList) {
        System.out.println(shape.toString());
    }
```

no suitable method found for add(RightTriangle)
        shapeList.add(triangle_right);

error: cannot find symbol
        Comparable.sort(shapeList);

Comment: You should change `Comparable.sort(shapeList)` to `Collections.sort(shapeList)`.  You should also use a type parameter when you declare _shapeList_... like this: List<Shape> shapeList = new ArrayList<Shape>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the other answers, you could define your `Comparator` and sort your array as follows:

```
Arrays.sort(myArray, new Comparator<MyClass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass c1, MyClass c2) {
        return (new Double(c1.getRatio())).compareTo(c2.getRatio());
    }
});
```

If you plan sorting multiple arrays like this, it would be wise to make `MyClass` implement the `Comparable` interface.

---

***EDIT***: To sort `List`s (such as `ArrayList`s) you can use a similar concept, but with `Collections.sort`:

```
Collections.sort(shapeList, new Comparator<MyClass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass c1, MyClass c2) {
        return (new Double(c1.getRatio())).compareTo(c2.getRatio());
    }
});
```

---

Relevant documentation:

- [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)
- [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)
- [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29)
- [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: In my code I am getting an error for incompatible types for shapeList. But is that what I am looking for?

Comment: @ElmirKouliev What is `shapeList`?

Comment: @ElmirKouliev Is this an `ArrayList` (or other `List`) or just an array? i.e. how is the variable defined?

Comment: You should include a type parameter when you define your ArrayList.  Otherwise it will be assumed that your list contains Objects.  An Object is not the same as a Shape.  You should declare your list like this:  `List<Shape> shapeList = new ArrayList<Shape>();`

Comment: We can't read your mind.  If you're getting errors and you'd like help, you'll have to share some details.  Also, the point of this site is not for people to hold your hand while walking through every step of completing your homework assignment.  If you've stumbled onto a new error, plese edit your question accordingly.  Otherwise, consider creating a new question that is related to your new error. How do you expect us to respond to "_I'm getting two errors_" if that's all you tell us?  We can't see the code you're typing!!

Comment: I had included them in the code, I apologize for not specifying that.

Comment: @ElmirKouliev - If the code in your question is current, I'll re-iterate my last comment: you need to specify a type argument when you declare your list.  See the comment I made an hour ago.  Using a non-typed List is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for the [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method. In your case it would look sth like this (I assume the `getRatio` method is in a common `Shape` class/interface):

```
public class ShapeComparator implements Comparator<Shape> { 
    int compareTo (final Shape shape1, final Shape shape2) {
        return (int) Math.signum (shape1.getRatio () - shape2.getRatio ());
    }
}
```

You can also make your common class implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface,like this:

```
public class Shape implements Comparable<Shape> {
    int compareTo (final Shape other) {
        return (int) Math.signum (getRatio () - other.getRatio ());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make your Object implement *Comparable*.

[More info here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

You'll want to implement *compareTo()* so it compares the ratio of the two objects.

Here's how you might do that:

```
class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {

    private double ratio;

    public double getRatio() {
        return ratio;
    }

    public int compareTo(Foo otherFoo) {
        if (otherFoo == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return ratio - otherFoo.ratio;
    }

}
```

---

Here's how you would sort a Collection of Foo objects:

```
List<Foo> fooList = createFooList();
Collections.sort(fooList);

// print the Foos in order

for (Foo f : fooList) {
    System.out.println(f.toString());
}
```

Comment: i have set up a compare to method, just not sure how to implement it into an array using objects

Comment: If your object implements _Comparable_, its _compareTo_ method will automatically be used to sort Collections that are ordered.  You can also sort a Collection by using _Collections.sort(someCollection);_

Comment: So then after they are ordered, how do I call the toString methods of these objects, in the order created by the Comparable

Comment: Iterate over your ordered collection and call _toString()_ on each item in the Collection.  Hint: use a for loop.

Comment: I was able to set up an array that applies the comparator

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use an Array or a Collection.  Both of them will use your _compareTo_ method when sorted.  You can sort an array with _Arrays.sort()_ and you can sort a Collection with _Collections.sort()_.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19788/discussion-between-elmir-kouliev-and-jahroy)